How to replicate the Zsh command line prompt from the archlinux boot USB stick
It looks very nice and useful. Is there a theme I can download to install it quickly?

It's part of grml-zsh-config originating from https://grml.org/zsh/. Install it on Archlinux with:
sudo pacman -S grml-zsh-config

